# Mistake in determining period of a parametric motion

Tags: parametric

> The position of an object in circular motion is modelled by the given parametric equations. Describe the path of the object by stating the radius of the circle, the position at time $t = 0$, the orientation of the motion (clockwise or counterclockwise), and the time $t$ that it takes to complete one revolution around the circle.
>   $$x=\sin7t,y=\cos7t$$

I found the radius which is 1. The position at time $t=0$ is $(0,1)$. The orientation is clockwise because $x$ is increasing and $y$ is decreasing. However, for the last part I tried $t=\pi$ and $t=2\pi/3$ but both answers were wrong and I can't figure out why so.

Comment: $7t=2\pi$ for a complete period...